# Is it possible to use the install4j HTTP credential dialog for custom actions?

Tags: install4j

I need to write a custom rest client to be able to handle single-sign-on authentication in some purposes. The client has to decide whether to use sso or basic authentication. For the basic authentication a dialog should appear and the user will be asked for the credentials. In install4j there already exists such a dialog and I wonder whether I can reuse this dialog to get the credentials and set these to the custom rest client?

Answer (score 0):

That information is not saved, so you cannot retrieve it later. Conversely, you could set the system properties "serverAuthUser" and "serverAuthPassword", so install4j would use this for authentication and the password dialog would not be shown.